# Can't delete Celery Task

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I'm having a very weird Issue, I mounted a Django app with Docker, and added a Redis DB to implement Celery tasks, now, yesterday everything was working perfectly, but today I created a new task to test, and now I can't get rid of it, it is on a permanent state of pending, and doesn't matter what I do, I can't stop current_app.AsyncResult(task_status.task_id) from returning it with the pending state.

I've tried to remove it `celery -A proj purge`, `current_app.control.purge()`, `task.revoke()`, and `current_app.control.revoke(task.id, terminate=True)`. But despite that it is still returning it. This is how my Redis DB looks like now:

[image]

There are no tasks ids, Am I doing something wrong, or is there something that I'm misunderstanding?

My structure looks something like this:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

services:

  django:
    image: "test:latest"
    command: python manage.py runserver
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - ${PORT_OUT}:8000
    networks:
      - backend
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  db:
    # DB parameters

  celery:
    image: "test:latest"
    command: celery -A djangoproject worker -l debug
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - backend
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis
      - db

  redis:
    image: "redis:7.0"
    container_name: "redis"
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
        - ./cache:/data

volumes:
  cache:
    driver: local
```

When I run this:

```
task = current_app.AsyncResult(task_id)
print(task)
print(task.status)
```

It keeps returning:

[image]

Which doesn't make sense, How can I delete the task, or why is it always in pending, and not failed or success? When I created the task, I remember that the Celery worker showed to have taked it and completed, so I'm not sure why is in that permanent state of pending, but that's what is breaking my code.